# How can I load a wasm file under node_modules as asset in snowpack?(for sql.js)

Tags: webpack, webassembly, emscripten, snowpack, sql.js

I want to use the [sql.js library](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js/), which uses wasm to provide sql support in browser.

To use this library in a React project, sql.js recommends using craco.js to extend the webpack config in CRA and use the [file-loader package of webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader) to fetch the wasm file from the node_modules directory.

You can look at the official react demo code for sql.js [here](https://github.com/sql-js/react-sqljs-demo). The specific lines of code: [import wasm file](https://github.com/sql-js/react-sqljs-demo/blob/59c133b2e23c449ca8fc628e35bc537f9d185dae/src/App.js#L6), [use file](https://github.com/sql-js/react-sqljs-demo/blob/59c133b2e23c449ca8fc628e35bc537f9d185dae/src/App.js#L17)

Snowpack suggests to use the browser's native `WebAssembly` and `fetch` APIs, but sql.js seems to require a uri for the wasm file. How can I achieve that in snowpack?

PS: sql.js uses [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html) to compile SQLite to wasm